# How can I generate an 16-character long MD5 hash in Java?

Tags: kotlin, md5

I need to generate on Kotlin a MD5 hash for some data, but as 16-character string, not a 32-character string. I found no way for that at this point and need help. But there is definitely a method, since I found website, which do it correctly.

For example these sites:

- https://www.freecodeformat.com/md516.php
- https://www.freecodeformat.com/md5.php

As a control I am using this string  - "1681799732000". The first site generates the correct answer with 16 characters - "92AA8DDBE039D480", The second link - 32 digit string - "E292561C92AA8DDBE039D4808CC51159".

Generating 32 character MD5 in Kotlin not a problem, but 16 character - actually is.

EDIT 1 - Encoding is presumably UTF-8

Comment: It's not possible to represent an MD5 (128 bits) in 16 printable characters. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have to implement some login function, which uses this md5 string in some algorithm. The links described in my message do exactly what I need, since I have a control string. I.e it is possible in some way. Please, look the link ...md516. There is a button labeled MD5 Hash_16 Uppercase. It gives me the right control string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your control string into each of those you get back:

```
16:         92aa8ddbe039d480
32: e292561c92aa8ddbe039d4808cc51159
```

The 16 character result appears to be the 32 character result with the first and last 8 characters removed.

Comment: Wow! Thanks. What happened with me, lol? I am overtired :)

Comment: While this may be what OP was looking for, this doesn’t answer the question actually asked. The question asks how to generate a 16-character MD5 hash, to which the answer is “you can’t”. Taking a substring of the hash defeats the purpose because it may no longer be unique. There’s no reason to hash anything, just take 16 characters from the original string and call it good.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Hashes are by definition not unique. Taking a substring of a hash is a very common way of generating a hash with a smaller bit space. There is a big difference between using first 16 chars of a string and taking first 16 chars of a hash of a string - the latter has its own uses. But you are correct: we can't say this is a "16-character MD5 hash". It is a 32-chars MD5 with some custom post-processing.

Comment: @broot I’m not aware of any definition of a hash code that demands it to not be unique, so, I don’t know what definition you’re alluding to. Although it doesn’t have to produce unique codes, a good hash function is intended to map _uniformly_ over its range, which would  naturally create unique hash codes as far as possible. That said, I think enough has been said with regards to OP’s vague question, so, I’m going to leave it here.

Comment: Wouldn't that be determined by the entropy of the source (i.e., the string being hashed) compared to the code rate of the hash algorithm? Since we have a infinite number of input string possibilities and a finite set of hashed values, there must be a collision?

Answer (score -1):

You can’t generate a 16-character MD5 hash, but you can try to use a trick to get a 16-character unique string if that fits your use case.

1. First, create a MD5 hash from the given string. Then, take the first 16 characters from it.
2. If the resulting string is not in the database, it's unique, and you’re done. Otherwise, continue to step 3.
3. Append a predetermined string to your original string. Then, go to step 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't need to create a unique string as is. I need to get the exact algorithm for getting the 16 character string as described. You can check it with links provided. I am using some already existing api, which takes this 16-character hash, generated as described above.